# Importing multiple .csv files into R, having unequal rows

Tags: r

I want to merge multiple csv files in one data frame.
i have 22 csv files with 1 attribute each and with unequal number of rows

I have used this code but getting errors

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
df<-data.frame(myfiles)
```

Error:

```
Error in data.frame(list(Auto = c(67L, 964L, 730L, 443L, 1191L, 160L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1193, 193, 737, 1468, 3500, 3707, 3499, 3459, 1211, 5029, 5024, 2804, 3226, 3439, 2004, 2092, 2778
```

Comment: Can you make up a small example set of input files and show what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 1):

If all the files are really guaranteed to have one attribute, `rbind` should do just fine. We can use it succinctly like so:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(pattern = "*.csv"), read.csv))
```

We apply `read.csv` to each file name and return a `list` of `data.frame` using `lapply`. We then use `do.call` to feed all the data frames as arguments to `rbind`.

Answer (score 0):

In the **plyr** package there is a function rbind.fill that will merge data.frames and introduce NA for empty cells:

```
library(plyr)
concat <- rbind.fill(mtcars[c("mpg", "wt")], mtcars[c("wt", "cyl")])
concat[25:40, ]

 mpg    wt cyl
25 19.2 3.845  NA
26 27.3 1.935  NA
27 26.0 2.140  NA
28 30.4 1.513  NA
29 15.8 3.170  NA
30 19.7 2.770  NA
31 15.0 3.570  NA
32 21.4 2.780  NA
33   NA 2.620   6
34   NA 2.875   6
35   NA 2.320   4
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer but after executing your given command,i got dataframe but 1st attribute is taking all the 22 csv file values and remaining all are NAs. Please help me out